# grails console failing to execute a script after it's opened as .groovy

Tags: testing, grails, grails-orm

I am using the grails console to test my code as I'm finding it very unproductive to run even basic unit tests efficiently from STS.

Anyway, when I cut and paste the code into the console it runs fine. However when I save the code snippet as a .groovy script and then reopen it later and try and run it, it fails with a generic:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: xxx for class: yyy
```

The script runs fine if I copy the code and paste into into a new window!

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was wrong with this and wanted to update here in case it useful for someone else.

One of my domain objects is called:

```
HierarchyNode
```

and I saved the groovy script as HierarchyNode.grooy.

As a result when the following code was executed in the console, it failed:

```
def root = new HierarchyNode(['name': 'Root Node', 'company': comp, 'customer': cust, 'isRoot': true, 'nodeProperties': ['prop1': 'value1', 'prop2': 'value2']])
```

with this exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: HierarchyNode at HierarchyNode.run(HierarchyNode.groovy:6)
```

Renaming the script to not clash with the domain object resolved the issue.